# What are the characteristics of המשכלים in Daniel 12?

Tags: words, hebrew, translation, daniel-book-of

I would like to know more about the word הַ֨מַּשְׂכִּלִ֔ים which I highlight in a bold face in the texts below.

Daniel 12:3 is

וְ**הַ֨מַּשְׂכִּלִ֔ים** יַזְהִ֖רוּ כְּזֹ֣הַר הָרָקִ֑יעַ וּמַצְדִּיקֵי֙ הָֽרַבִּ֔ים כַּכּוֹכָבִ֖ים לְעוֹלָ֥ם וָעֶֽד

Which is translated into English in [sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.12.3?lang=bi) as

And the **knowledgeable** will be radiant like the bright expanse of sky, and those who lead the many to righteousness will be like the stars forever and ever.

My question refers to what characteristics the meaning of הַ֨מַּשְׂכִּלִ֔ים contains. It is translated as knowledgeable which is similar to wise but wise is חָכָם like in many places in the Proverbs.

הַ֨מַּשְׂכִּלִ֔ים appears also in Daniel 12:10:

יִ֠תְבָּֽרְר֠וּ וְיִֽתְלַבְּנ֤וּ וְיִצָּֽרְפוּ֙ רַבִּ֔ים וְהִרְשִׁ֣יעוּ רְשָׁעִ֔ים וְלֹ֥א יָבִ֖ינוּ כׇּל־רְשָׁעִ֑ים וְ**הַמַּשְׂכִּלִ֖ים** יָבִֽינוּ

which is translated in [sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.12.3?lang=bi) as

Many will be purified and purged and refined; the wicked will act wickedly and none of the wicked will understand; but the **knowledgeable** will understand.

I understand that it refers not to knowledge itself but to a righteous conduct of one's life. What other characteristics does it have? How it differs from חָכָם?

I have read the commentaries in sefaria.org on Daniel 12:3 and Daniel 12:10 but they don't detail הַ֨מַּשְׂכִּלִ֔ים

Comment: There are lots of different terms for wisdom / cleverness e.g. chochmah, binah and daas. The term Seichel I always understood as common sense